# This question has solution but is the question valid in the first place?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Q. Let $f:[1,\infty)\to [2,\infty)$ be a differentiable function such that $f(1)=2$. If $6 \int_1^x f(t)dt=3xf(x)-x^3$ for all $x \geq 1 $, then the value of $f(2)$ is ?

---

**My approach:**

I first differentiated the equation to get

$$6f(x)=3f(x)+3xf'(x)-3x^2$$

This is Linear differentiational equation which on solving gives ,

$$f(x)=x^2+cx$$

Putting $f(1)=2$ we get $c=1$,

$$\therefore f(x)=x^2+x$$

So $f(2) = 6$.

---

But if we put $x=1$ in the equation given in the question we get,
$$6 \int_1^1 f(t)dt=3(1)f(1)-1^3$$
$$0=5$$

This is IIT-JEE 2011 Question and is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It was a bonus. the candidates of the exam were given full score for this question.